# What is the number of bit-strings of length $6$ where the number of $0$'s is equal to the number of $1$'s?

Tags: combinatorics

For example, there are two such strings of length two: $01$ and $10$.
We know It must contain exactly  three $0$'s and three $1$'s 
So It would be $c(6,3) \cdot c(6,3)$ what's wrong here??

also What is the number of sequences of six digits where the number of even digits is equal to the number of odd digits?

For example, there are 50 such sequences of length two: 01, 03, 05, 07, 09, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, ..., 90, 92, 94, 96, 98.

for the second one I didn't even understand the question

Comment: Once you have chosen the places for the zeros, you are done; you have no choice about the placing of the ones.

Comment: is that means 6 choose 3

Comment: Are repeats allowed in the second question? In other words, is 000333 a valid sequence?

Comment: @TiwaAina  34  no repeats not allowed

Comment: @moustafasoama Then my answer should be correct

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of 6 digit natural numbers with 3 odd and 3 even digits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2435850/number-of-6-digit-natural-numbers-with-3-odd-and-3-even-digits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question:

We have $6$ zeroes and we need to choose $3$ of them to be changed into ones. Hence there are $\binom 63 = 20$ such bit strings.

---

For your second question, I assume repeats aren't allowed:

We have six spots, and we must fill three of them with evens and other three with odds. So the amount of combinations for each spot would be

$$\color{blue}{\binom 53} \cdot \binom 53$$

where blue signifies evens digits ($0,2,4,6,8$) and black signifies odd digits ($1, 3, 5, 7, 9$).

But after choosing our combinations in this way, we need to consider all possible orders! And since the number of ways we can reorder $n$ objects is $n!$, we see that our final answer is $${\binom 53} \cdot \binom 53 \cdot 6! = 72000$$

Comment: got it do you know how to write simple script to check for the second question

Comment: what if repetition is allowed?? @Tiwa Aina

Comment: @moustafasoama This is a small enough problem, so I'd just make a nested for loop of depth 6 to choose every digit from 0 to 9 and check if it satisfies the requirements.

Comment: @moustafasoama If it's allowed, then the problem becomes much more difficult. I don't think there would be a good way short of casework.

Comment: so I want to know how to write condition to check for this in python

Comment: so I want to know how to write condition to check for this in python if the repetition not allowed what would the condition be @Tiwa Aina

Comment: @moustafasoama Put the numbers in an array and search for duplicates. If any exist, do not increment the count.

Comment: count=0      
from itertools import permutations 
for i in permutations(range(10), 6):
       if i[0]%2==0 and i[1]%2==0 and i[2]%2==0 and i[3]%2!=0 and i[4]%2!=0 and i[5]%2!=0 : 
         
        count+=1
        print(i)      
print(count) 
what's wrong here

Comment: it gives me 3600 @TiwaAina please  show me your code or how to modify my condition

Comment: @moustafasoama This only checks for sequences like 204371, but won't catch 203471, even though it's a valid sequence. For each permutation, you need to iterate over the entire thing and check whether exactly 3 of the numbers are even.

Comment: but 3600 equal 5P3 times 5P3

Comment: and it's only display the even numbers on the first three spots and the ood's ones on the rest how can I make it mix them if I do so my condition becomes messy @TiwaAina

Comment: my code only permutes  the even numbers and then the odd numbers so it's equal  2(5P3)  @TiwaAina

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68895/discussion-between-moustafa-soama-and-tiwa-aina).